# How can I pass values to the browser from Shiny so that JavaScript can use them?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to make R Shiny communicate with Javascript. I have successfully created a js script that looks for a span tag and replaces it with "He" or "She" depending on a gender information that I provide in server.r. So if candidateGender == 1, JavaScript plugs in "She" for candidateGender == 0, JS plugs in "He".

This works if I use the HTML() function straight from the UI.r. However, when I pass it on from server.r through a renderText to htmlOutput combo it does not work either.

Below are the three scripts. Note that the JavaScript has to be inserted in a folder called 'www' and saved in the same folder as the ui and server files.

UI:

```
library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      tags$head(tags$script(src="pronoun_selector.js")),
      ### this works
                          HTML('<strong> This works: </strong>
                                <p>
                                    He/She: 
                                    <span class="replace-text-pronoun">he/she</span> 
                                    His/Her: 
                                    <span class="replace-text-posessive">his/her</span> 

                                </p>'),

       ### this doesn't                   
                          HTML('<strong> This does not work: </strong>'),
                          htmlOutput("statement")
    )
```

SERVER:

```
library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #select gender
  candidateGender <-  "1" #1 == Female; 2 == Male

  #pass to customMessage handler
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage('replaceTextCallbackHandler', candidateGender) #### set up the callback handler
  })


  output$statement <- renderText({
    'He/She: 
     <span class="replace-text-pronoun">he/she</span> '
    }) 

}
```

JavaScript (save as pronoun_selector.js in folder www):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("replaceTextCallbackHandler",     
    function(candidateGender) { //candidateGender is set in server.r

      var pronounTextF = 'she';
      var pronounPosessiveTextF = 'her';
      var pronounTextM = 'he';
      var pronounPosessiveTextM = 'his';

      var pronouns = $('.replace-text-pronoun');
      var pronounsPosessive = $('.replace-text-posessive');

      if (candidateGender === '0') {
        pronouns.text(pronounTextM);
        pronounsPosessive.text(pronounPosessiveTextM);
      }
      else if (candidateGender === '1') {
        pronouns.text(pronounTextF);
        pronounsPosessive.text(pronounPosessiveTextF);
      }
      else {
        console.log(candidateGender);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your javascript code is only called once, when the app starts. At that point, the renderUI hasn't been called yet, so your javascript is executed before the HTML is generated. You need to somehow call the javascript function only after the renderUI function has run

Comment: Thanks @daattali this makes a lot of sense. I guess this is not a real R/Shiny problem and more of a JS problem. Thanks for finding the problem.

Comment: In case anybody else runs into it. Using @daattali suggestions I refined my googling and found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/ZvXb-y3TFTE . This resolves the issue.